# stop previous event when next one on the same is fired

Tags: javascript

```
searchBox.live('input', function(){
    //search in a json object
    //update the dom based mathes
});
```

How do i stop the previous search when a new input is entered in the searchbox

Comment: Take a look at [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), if you can get the reference to the search event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your goal is to search only after user finished typing, right? In such case delay the actual execution of the search in this manner:

```
var searchTimer = 0;
searchBox.live('input', function(){
    window.clearTimeout(searchTimer);
    searchTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        //search in a json object
        //update the dom based mathes
    }, 500);
});
```

This will trigger the search half a second after user entered input and cancel all previous calls.

Comment: my goal is to stop the previous search mid way and start the new one

Comment: @WebDeveloper that's not possible, unless you add complex logic to the search itself (server side). Once AJAX request has been sent, you can't cancel it. Did you try what I suggested here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at underscores [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function. You pass it the function and a *wait* millisecond value and it returns a "debounced" version of the function that queues up incoming function calls and executes the last one in the queue after *wait* ms.